# iptables nonexistent?

Tags: iptables

```
$ iptables
sh: 1: iptables: not found
$ sudo iptables
[sudo] password for [redacted]: 
sudo: iptables: command not found
$ /sbin/iptables
sh: 3: /sbin/iptables: not found
$ sudo /sbin/iptables
sudo: /sbin/iptables: command not found
```

iptables was removed from my computer somehow. How would I access it?

Comment: @muru It wasn't even installed. Weird. But it's fixed now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case `iptables` is not installed or the binary is missing, try installing/re-installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables
```